# Generic array type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have function with generic type.

But it return an error `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

```
function testing<K, V>(array: Array<{ key: K, value: V }>): Array<V> {
    return array.map(data => data.value)
}

testing([{ key: 1, value: "one" }, { key: 2, value: true }])
```

How can I fix this generic type issue with keeping the type generic. Because the array is unknown and the value may have different custom type.

Comment: If it can be of any type at all, why use a generic type? Just use `any`, no?

Comment: We'll use that type later, so `any` type should be avoided

Comment: The replacement of `any` is `unknown`, it forces the caller to type check it.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK958N) meet your needs?

Comment: But if you're returning an array of generic type <V>, but in the input array, v can be of any type, I don't know how you work around using `any` or `unknown`.

Comment: You are also ignoring K

Comment: Well using K helps make sure the key is always of the same type (you couldn't run `testing([{ key: 1, value: "one" }, { key: 'two', value: true }])`, for example)

Comment: The value may have graphQL type and we will use that type later. Therefore, we cannot use `any` or `unknown`.

Comment: But the point is that the return value will not be an Array of a single type, as demonstrated by your example. Therefore, if you get an array of a variety of types, how do you plan to use it?

Comment: I simplified the problem. The function will input a different graphQL and return the result.
`function testing<K, V>(array: Array<{ key: K, graphQL: V }>): Array<V> {
    ... for loop run graphQL
    return [graphQL result]
}`
Therefore, I cannot use `any` or `unknown` in my function.

Comment: And you would also need the return type to be a tuple so that Typescript will give you the proper type when you iterate. But it won’t be very useful as these types will not exist at runtime. So I think you will need to use type predicates to get the runtime type.

Answer (score 1):

TS apparently isn't smart enough to infer V being an union type, so for tricky arguments like that you'll have to declare it explicitly.

```
function testing<K, V>(array: Array<{ key: K, value: V }>): Array<V> {
    return array.map(data => data.value)
}

testing<number, string | boolean>(
    [{ key: 1, value: "one" }, { key: 2, value: true }]
); // works, TS is told explicitly what V is

testing(
    [{ key: 1, value: "one" }, { key: 2, value: "two" }]
); // works, TS correctly infers string
```

Comment: was able to get it working below without knowing ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

The following will extract the `type` of each value and return the union:

```js
type ArrayValueTypes<MyValueArray extends { value: unknown }[]> = {
    [K in keyof MyValueArray]: MyValueArray[K]['value']
}

const myArray = [{ key: 1, value: "one" }, { key: 2, value: true }]

function testing<T extends { value: any }[]>(array: T): ArrayValueTypes<T> {
    return array.map(data => data.value)
}

const result = testing(myArray)
// result is of type (string | boolean)[]
```

[Typescript playground example!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAaogNgVwgFXBAZwB4BZVDbeJEKCAD2AgDsATAqAbygDcKIAuKJiYBrJgHsA7kygBfANoBdAHxQAvJwBQUHVHkBpKAEsZIiCHEAzKGTRYIVZIsG2+jkAcXyA5L3vfFTVlNTQBjcSYCYCgAWxB3dT0uMxBBAEYAGh4+QQAiCIhcuSzk80EAJiy-bEFgOGw5QM1LYVDgIwioRiiTAHMiHFoGZjZObPtBYTEpGQUVAApEBGRBHABKQXc7bDxIYhxVDm1dOAhgTDgZJeoAOhjEMHmWRGBEdVVn15vqiDWgkPCkWipwImHQ0Q03XaTF68zi7j+AHpEbooAA9AD8mmRUBBYOiRnYVi6+Cg8yicD6UAAPlAAEbicToCCIJhrJRAA)

Comment: The OP explained  that they don't know all the types `value` could be.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really know the type of `value` is. You should use `unknown` to force users to type check it.

I also don't see why you need `key` and `K` since they are ignored.

```
function testing(array: Array<{value: unknown }>): Array<unknown> {
    return array.map(data => data.value);
}

testing([{ key: 1, value: "one" }, { key: 2, value: true }])
```

Comment: "I also don't see why you need key and K since they are ignored" - try calling `testing([{ key: "one", value: "one" }, { key: 2, value: "two" }])`.

Comment: @mbojko That is the technical side of it. The OP potentially wants to ensure the data has a key property of the same type in every item. However, It's odd and  potentially wrong that a function would enforce the type of something that it does not care about.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
function testing<K, V>(array: Array<{ key: K, value: V }>): Array<V> {
    return array.map(data => data.value)
}

testing<number, string | boolean>([{ key: 1, value: "one" }, { key: 2, value: true }])
```